# upload image in c# and show messagebox in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

I'm making a program which will upload **only bitmaps**. If the user tries to upload anything other extension it should popup an error message.

```
OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
op.Title = "Open Image";
op.Filter = "bmp files (*.bmp)|*.bmp";
if (op.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(op.FileName));
}
if ( op.ShowDialog() !== FilterEventArgs)
{
    MessageBox.Show ( your path doesn't bmp ); 
}
```

How can I correct this code and what is the right parameter to put in if statement to show the messagebox?

Comment: Your question is rather unclear, and even making some educated guesses it looks like there's multiple problems with this code fragment. For example, it loads the file into memory before checking the type. I think you need to take a step back and check out the MSDN reference for OpenFileDialog.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Image image = new Image();
        OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
        op.Title = "Open Image";
        op.Filter = "bmp files (*.bmp)|*.bmp";

        bool bNotBmp = true;
        while (op.ShowDialog() == true && bNotBmp == true)
        {
           FileInfo FileInf = new FileInfo(op.FileName);
           string ImgExtension = FileInf.Extension;
           if (FileInf.Extension.ToString().ToLower() != ".bmp")
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Please upload only bmp file");
           }
           else
           {
               bNotBmp = false;
           }

        }

        MessageBox.Show("Write image or operation cancelled.");
```

Comment: Your code only allow .bmp selection and if user enter any other format file that you can handle this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
op.Title = "Open Image";
op.Filter = "bmp files (*.bmp)|*.bmp";

var result = op.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    if(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(op.FileName).ToLower() == ".bmp"){
        image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(op.FileName));
    }
    else{
        MessageBox.Show ("The file must have a .bmp extension"); 
    }
}
```